# Evaluate the integral using the theory of residues: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(x^2+1)^2(x^2+16)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(x^2+1)^2(x^2+16)}$$

**My attempt:**

We are integrating over the real axis, which is the real part of a set of complex numbers, so
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dz}{(z^2+1)^2(z^2+16)}$$

$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dz}{((z+i)(z-i))^2(z+4i)(z-4i)}$$

But I notice that all of the singularities are imaginary! Should this give me pause? What should I do now?

Comment: Close the loop, as always.

Comment: A semicircular contour with residue theorem can do the trick.

Comment: The fact that the singularities are purely imaginary makes literally no difference.  Semicircular contour as Henry said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the contour $\Gamma$ consisting of the line segment joining $(-\rho, 0)$ to $(\rho, 0)$ enclosed by the upper semicircle $C : |z| = \rho$. It is clear that $\Gamma$ is the boundary of a simple closed region.

Hence by the Residue Theorem, $\int_\Gamma f = 2\pi i \operatorname{Res}(f; \, z_i)$, where $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z^2+1)^2 (z^2+16)}$ and $z_i$ are the enumeration of the singularities in $\Gamma$.

On the other hand, $\int_\Gamma f = \int_{-\rho}^\rho f + \int_C f$. Rearranging and sending $\rho \to \infty$, we find that the integral to be computed is

$$I=2\pi i \operatorname{Res}(f; \, z_i)-\int_C f.$$

It can be shown that the integral $\int_C f$ vanishes. Thus, all that remains to be done is to compute the residues of $f$ in $\Gamma$.

Comment: So I did it using the first method you suggested and found that the sum of all residues $=0$. My singular points were $z=i,-i,4i,-4i$ where the points at $i$ and $-i$ were of order 2. Any suggestions?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat Note that $-i$ and $-4i$ are not inside the contour $\Gamma$.

Comment: Ah, right. Thanks!

Comment: @whatwhatwhat Always happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

You should integrate over a semicircle contour of radius $R$ centered at the origin. Name this contour $\gamma$ and consider the integral

$$ \int_\gamma f(z)dz $$

which can be calculated using the residue theorem. On the other hand, we can break up the contour into separate pieces: $\gamma = [-R,R] \cup C_R$, where $C_R$ is the semicircular part of the contour. Doing this we see that

$$ \int_\gamma f(z)dz = \int_{-R}^R f(x)dx + \int_{C_R}f(z)dz $$

We know the expression on the left from the residue theorem, and you can prove that as you let $R \to \infty$ the integral over $C_R$ vanishes. What you are left with after this happens is the result you are looking for.